# Update Record in SQL for a specific row

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am trying to update a record using sqlalchemy.

```
tableA.query().\
filter(tableA.id== 9080).\
update({"bankbalance": (tableA.bankbalance+1)})
tableA.commit()
```

In tableA, there are two columns - id and bankbalance.
I want to update the bankbalance for the person with id 9080.

But the query is not working because I am getting the error below.

TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **db.session.query()**, if you don't query a model.

```
db.session.query(tableA).filter(tableA.id == 9080).\
update({"bankbalance": (tableA.bankbalance+1)})
db.session.commit()
```